# Is there a study of world poverty rates over time pre 1800?

Tags: reference-request, poverty, history

There seems to be research showing that world poverty rates have declined since 1800, see eg [this](http://ourworldindata.org/data/growth-and-distribution-of-prosperity/world-poverty/#200-years-of-lifting-the-world-out-of-poverty). Is there any research on world poverty rates before this period? I am guessing that during this period poverty in much of the world would have gone up as a result of European colonisation.

Comment: How would you define poverty pre 1800?

Comment: maybe infant mortality or availability of food/shelter?

Comment: This paper may interest you: http://www.nber.org/papers/w8460

Answer (score 3):

This is only for Europe unfortunately, but Bob Allen has a famous paper in which he presents reconstructed data for real wages in different European cities from 1350 all the way to 1799:

> Allen, Robert C. "The great divergence in European wages and prices from the Middle Ages to the First World War." Explorations in economic history 38.4 (2001): 411-447.

From real wages and price data, he then infers a measure of (extreme) poverty.

Look at Figure 5 in the paper. The scale of the y-axis is a measure of poverty in which 1 is the poverty threshold. Values above 1 on the y-axis correspond to real wages lower than survival rate (i.e. that do not allow a survival caloric intake), and values above 1 indicate a real wage above survival rate.

Comment: I believe the data from the paper is publicly available on Bob Allen's website https://www.nuffield.ox.ac.uk/People/sites/Allen/SitePages/Biography.aspx.